# Displaying Django Models data in html file

Tags: django

I want to display data taken from my Django models in my html file. So in the code bellow instead of a 0  I want the donation model data. Can someone please help? Thank you! also if anyone knows a easier way please tell me. i can update my question again if anyone needs more details.

Views.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
# Create your views here.

def index(request,*args, **kwargs):
  return render(request, "index.html", {} )



@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def myview(request,id):
  data= userdetails.objects.get(id=id)
  return render(request,'dashboard.html',{'data':data}


def register(request ):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/dashboard/')
    else: 
        form = CreateUserForm()
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                messages.success(request, f'Your account has been successfully created, {username} ')
                return redirect('loginpage')
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, "register.html",  context )



def loginpage(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/dashboard/')
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            password =request.POST.get('password')

            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('/dashboard')
            else:
        
                messages.error(request, 'Username OR password is incorrect')

        context = {}
        return render(request, 'login.html', context)

def logoutuser(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')

@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def donate(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        title = request.POST['donationtitle']
        phonenumber = request.POST['phonenumber']
        category = request.POST['category']
        quantity = request.POST['quantity']
        location = request.POST['location']
        description = request.POST['description']
        ins = Donation(title = title, phonenumber = phonenumber, category = category, quantity = quantity, location = location, description = description, user=request.user, )
        ins.save()

    return render(request,'donate.html')
```

Error:

```
File "C:\Users\jbtai\coding\GoodDeedWeb\home\views.py", line 30
    def register(request ):
    ^
```

Comment: Your `userdetails` has a many-to-one relation with the user model, so that means a user can have *multiple* `userdetails`.

Comment: I know that, and I want to display only one of the relations in my html. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You need a view that handle that:

```
def myview(request):
  id = request.user.id
  data= userderails.objects.get(id=id)
  return render(request,'dashboard.html',{'data':data}
```

Then in your template 'dashboard.html' you could show details:

```
{{data.donations}}
{{data.points}}
```

use this url for that view instead of the old one

```
path('dashboard/',views.myview, name = 'dashboard' ),
```

Comment: That you for the detailed answer, I am a little confused as to what you mean by including the id parameter in my url. This is my url right now: `path('dashboard/', views.dashboard, name = 'dashboard' ),` what else do I need to include?

Comment: I'm getting some error, it has to do with another view and only comes up when I update my code with your solution. I am updating my question right now to include the error and all of the code for my views.py file

Comment: you didnt close the parenthesis in return render(request,'dashboard.html',{'data':data})

Comment: is there a more simple way to just get the data from the django models table and display it in the html?

Comment: i dont think so, its just it wasnt clear what you have a views, try the upated answer, this is a tested code that should work, good luck

Comment: Still doesn't work, now i'm getting an error saying DoesNotExist at /dashboard/
userdetails matching query does not exist.